# How to create three Y-axis in one graph?

Tags: matlab, graph

I have 3 sets of y data: (Y1a, Y1b, Y1c), (Y2a, Y2b, Y2c) and (Y3a, Y3b,Y3c) with the same x-axis x. I want to plot those data in one graph like this one

[image]

as you can see there are three Y-axis, the black circle, Red circle and Green Circle, with only one x-axis (temperature) so how can i do that?

Comment: haha you're welcome! Have fun!

Comment: Oh no. I don't know how to used it? this is the error" Not enough input arguments

Comment: can you edit your question with the code generating the problem?